# Is there a way to connect database table with dropdown list in work item for Azure DevOps Server

Tags: windows, azure, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I need to read content from table and show it in dropdown list in some work item type. The only way I managed to do it is to directly enter it in task.xml and it stays fixed like:

```
<allowedvalues name ="something">
<listitem value="something" />
<listitem value="something2" />
<listitem value="something3" />
```

The point is to be "dynamic" because the values changes weekly

So picture bellow demonstrates the current way of adding listitems that are fixed:

[image]

Comment: Please check if the answer below can resolve your issue, if yes, you could accept it as answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) .

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer: no.

The more elaborate answer: there is a custom work item control that can be linked to a REST API. So if you expose the database table through a REST API, and configure this custom work item control for the field.

Available extensions:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.vsts-rest-multivalue-control

Or you could build your own custom work item control and publish that as an extension to the marketplace. Anything the browser can access can be used to extend that UI.

**Note**: These custom controls work only in the Azure DevOps web UI. Excel and older versions of Visual Studio rely on a WinForms implementation for similar behavior. Nor will the client/server verify that the value must be one from your REST API, it will treat the field effectively as a simple string without validation. This means that any API based access will be able to write arbitrary values to that field.

### Alternatively:

Use a trigger or a job to generate the WIT xml and push it to the server using witadmin.